# Net Core: Type or namespace name 'RoleProvider' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.0

I am migrating a project from .Net 4.6.2 into .Net Core 2.0. What is the replacement for RoleProvider in Net Core?

The type or namespace name 'RoleProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 public class CustomerRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public override string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
```

New code looks like this, received error

```
Using the generic type 'RoleManager<TRole>' requires 1 type arguments

// Error first line: Using the generic type 'RoleManager<TRole>' requires 1 type arguments

public class CustomerRoleProvider : RoleManager
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    public void CreateRole(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string roleName)
    {
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

**Update:**
Answer from John Kenney looks great, hopefully someone can add more into his answer as edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RoleProvider` doesn't exist in .NET Core at least not in that form.
I believe what you are looking for is the `RoleManager`. The implementation is quite similar to the below:

```
var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Kindly refer to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/role-base-authorization-in-asp-net-core-2-1/) for detail on how to implement it.

Comment: so would I add CustomerManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<CustomerManager<IdentityRole>>();  ?,  how would I incorporate Customer? thanks

Comment: See this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/role-base-authorization-in-asp-net-core-2-1/

Comment: this answer is good, hoping it can be more explanation than just link, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers